# Getting "Intl is not defined" in Dataform GCP project

Tags: dataform, google-dataform

I'm working on a project in Dataform in the Google Cloud Plataform. I want to use an external package called `luxon` to deal with some DateTime requirements in my project. The code below is where I'm working with `luxon`:

```js
const { DateTime } = require('luxon')


const TABLE_SHARDING_YESTERDAY_SUFFIX = DateTime.utc().minus({ days: 1 }).toFormat('yyyyMMdd')

module.exports = {
  TABLE_SHARDING_YESTERDAY_SUFFIX
}
```

And when I try to compile my project, I get this error:

```
Intl is not defined
```

I searched about it, and I understood that the `Intl` is a built-in object correspond to the ECMAScript Internationalization API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl) and, by the error above, it is not available.

Is there any solution to fix that problem?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `Node.js` had some problems with `i18n` support. There is a [disussion on that topic](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/6371) on Github. Also they [clarified](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/6371#issuecomment-42955459) that there are some subtleties with ECMAScript standards support:

> ECMAScript 5.1 is defined by standard ECMA-262 edition 5.1, while the
> ECMAScript Internationalization API is defined by a separate
> complementary standard, ECMA-402

It means that `Node.js` runtime can implement ECMA-262 edition 5.1 and thus ECMAScript 5.1 without implementing ECMA-402.

Can you update your `Node.js` version? Looks like it could help to solve the issue since all locales are now included as of `Node.js v13`.

Also please note the issue [DateTime.fromFormat fails in some cases when running Node 18.13.0](https://github.com/moment/luxon/issues/1364) which is is caused by an update to ICU in `Node.js`.

`Node.js` versions `18.13+` [should support it](https://github.com/moment/luxon/pull/1369).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I cannot update the Node.js. The runtime environment of the GCP Dataform is abstract to me. I can only install packages when I add to my packages.json.

Comment: I think that, probably, you are on the different locale than `en-US`. If I am not mistaken, `toFormat()` defaults to `en-US` formatting. Try to investigate that. By the way, have you tried a different date format? Then did it work?